# vb.net find and replace text inside a textbox in Word

Tags: vb.net

I have this line of code which does a search and replace in a word document:

```
oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="Invoice", ReplaceWith:="Invoice - Paid: " + paid_date, Replace:=word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

Is there any way, i can do the search and replace inside a specific textbox in word rather than the whole document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it.

```
    For Each oCtl As Shape In doc.Shapes
        If oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
            oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Replace("Invoice", "Invoice - Paid: " + paid_date)
        End If
    Next
```

This essentially searches all the text boxes in your document and replaces "Invoice"

As an attempt to find the name of the textbox try this...

```
    For Each oCtl As Shape In doc.Shapes
        If oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
            MsgBox("Name: " & oCtl.Name & vbNewLine & "ID: " & oCtl.ID & vbNewLine & "Title: " & oCtl.Title & vbNewLine & "Text: " & oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
        End If
    Next
```

This should give you unique or identifiable items of every textbox.

then you could just go like this -

```
If oCtl.Name = "1234" then oCtl.Text.replace(whatever)
```

or ID or Title or whatever you decide to choose.

Comment: is there a way to search a specific textbox just in case there is another instance of the same word. i just want to replace one text box

Comment: Does the text box have a name or ID Number? is it on a specific page? ... In order to change a specific text box you need to tell me what's specific or special about it to correctly identify it from other textboxes -- even if its just a special word inside the box

Comment: There is a word (UNPAID) inside the box but I don't want to find and replace a specific word just in case there is 2 instances of it on the page. Is there a way to give the text box a name or ID and then find and replace just inside that text box?

Comment: is there a way of preserving formatting with this approach?